# Cancancan Select Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I am trying to customize a field on a cancancan object:

```
projectsAPI = Project.accessible_by(current_ability).select('projects.name, projects.price * 5 as new_price')
respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => {
                                    :project_data => projectsAPI
                                    }
                   }
```

The problem is when I check the API results, it just returns all the project fields, without any of the stuff in the `.select` statement.

When I check the log, the query has the custom fields in it, but also has the rest of the fields from projects.

How can I customize the fields in the json API return of the cancancan objects?

Answer (score 1):

How does the `.to_sql` look like?

Have you tried something like this with a sub query? That is how I often solve CanCan issues in regards to the joins it makes.

```
projectsAPI = Project.where("projects.id IN (?)", Project.accessible_by(current_ability).select(:id).to_sql).select('projects.name, projects.price * 5 as new_price')
```

Comment: Renders an error because it is still selecting all the fields in the subquery. If log the `Project.accessible_by(current_ability).select(:id).to_sql` it renders `SELECT "projects"."id", "projects"."id" AS t0_r0, "projects"."name"`... so basically the `.select(:id)` selects the `id` and then all the fields in the object anyway

Comment: I was able to get your suggestion to work with using .pluck(:id) in the subquery. However, a subquery is less efficient than just being able to select the right columns. Is there any other way besides `.select` to get custom fields out of active record?

Comment: I wouldn't do a pluck, because that will first extract all the ID's in a separate query, and that can fail if a lot of ID's are returned.

The reason CanCan selects more fields, is that it uses `.includes(...).references(...)` instead of `.left_joins(...)`. It can't do `.left_joins(...)` because the joins cache isn't shared with includes.

I believe there are issues in CanCanCan and Rails about both things. I will update my comment once I find them.

Comment: I see your point about pluck generating an Array.. but what other option is there? Doing an sql sub query just selects all fields and does not seem to work.

Comment: I am afraid you and the rest of us have to wait until the linked PR for Rails is merged and CanCanCan changes to left_joins instead of includes.references.

Comment: So `.accessible_by(current_ability)` seems to work on most objects I have as expected, it only glitches on the  `.select`  when the object has a `user_id` column. Probably because cancancan tries to join the users table.. Not sure if you want to add this to your tickets